# Maintaining state of ajax based countdown timer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, timer

I have created a countdown timer with the help of a code on internet by Member 4332221 on Code Project with some updates in it and I am using this timer on a project for online testing

Following is the code

aspx code

```
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID= "SM1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" 
Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick"></asp:Timer>
</div>

<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" 
runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName ="tick" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!SM1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
        Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString();
}

protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
    {
        int hrs = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
        ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes)) / 60;

        int mins = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
        ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes)) % 60;

        int seconds = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
        ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds))%60;


        lblTimer.Text = "Time left is " + hrs.ToString() + " : " + mins.ToString() + " : " + seconds.ToString();

        if (hrs == 0 && mins == 0 && seconds == 0)
        {
            lblTimer.Text = "Test Time Over";
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working properly if I am running it alone but the problem is that if I apply this in my module where I want to start this on button click event it works only once and while clicking on any other button the timer goes back to initial position.

I tried to apply `Postback = false` but then the timer is not displaying.

How can I load this timer on button click and maintain its state on click event of other controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your `Page_Load` event with following .. i just added one condition `(Session["timeout"] == null || Convert.ToString(Session["timeout"]).Trim() == "")`

this is my aspx code

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Clickkkk" onclick="btn2_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

following is my .cs code i as you can see i already have button and value persist on click of the button

---

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!SM1.IsInAsyncPostBack && (Session["timeout"] == null || Convert.ToString(Session["timeout"]).Trim() == ""))
            Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3).ToString();
    }
    protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
        {
            int hrs = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
            ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes)) / 60;

            int mins = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
            ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes)) % 60;

            int seconds = (((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
            ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds)) % 60;


            lblTimer.Text = "Time left is " + hrs.ToString() + " : " + mins.ToString() + " : " + seconds.ToString();

            if (hrs == 0 && mins == 0 && seconds == 0)
            {
                lblTimer.Text = "Test Time Over";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("asdasdsa");
    }
```

---

Comment: Thanks Dhawal! But it is not working, I am trying to fire this on button click event that earlier was applied on Page_Load

Comment: means you don want this on page_load

Comment: No! I want it on button click also I want to maintain its state on any other button click

Comment: i am not able to understand your requirement .. sorry .. but i am putting my test project code .. it might help you

Comment: Thanks! I hope it will help, where will you put that

Comment: I applied this and I loaded the session on another button click (that we are loading on Page Load), now while I am running this the project is not running

Comment: can you please check it now ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37094/discussion-between-dhaval-and-hanumendra)

Comment: Hi Dhawan! Can we discuss it now

Comment: sorry hamendra i wont be avilable now

Comment: Its ok Dhaval, please tell when you will be available and I apologize for misspelling your name

Comment: While running first time it is giving error object reference not set to an instance of an object on this line
if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))

Comment: Hi Dhaval! I have fixed it and it is running, thanks
I have marked your answer

Comment: thx and sorry i was a bit busy in the morning then i forgot completely .. sorry again